# Is there a way to run a shell script as one whole task(with single PID)?

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I have a shell script called run.sh. In it, I may call other shell scripts like:

```
./run_1.sh
./run_2.sh
.........
```

If I call the script by ./run.sh, I have found actually it will invoke different tasks inside the script sequentially with different PIDs(i.e., run_1.sh will be a task and run_2.sh will be another task). This disables me to kill the whole group of tasks using one "kill" command or run the whole group of tasks all in background by running "./run.sh &".
So is there a way to run the script just as one whole task?

Comment: A shell script is by definition `fork`-ing processes (for executing the executables), so it cannot be a single PID... (even if the shell process has a single PID).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- `pkill` can be used for killing the children of a process, using the `-P` option.

  ```
  pkill -P $PID
  ```

  where $PID is the PID of the parent process.
- You can `source` the `run_1.sh` command so that it is executed in the same shell *(This could cause side effects, since now all scripts will share the same scope)*.

  ```
  source run_1.sh
  source run_2.sh
  ```

Comment: But do you know what if the script containing an executable called a.out. Should I use ./a.out or source a.out? And what if the run_1.sh and run_2.sh also contain other scripts like run_1_1.sh? Should I apply source to all of them?

Comment: You can only run an executable without `source`-ing it (because its ELF format is not a valid sh syntax), and it will be run in its own process.